# Azure CLI pipeline task hanging on ADO

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, pipeline, azure-cli

I've written a simple AzureCLI script which should update a variable group value for a project. I've tested the script locally and this workds find so I know its an ADO issue, this script is:

```
echo $Pat_key| az devops login
az devops configure -d organization=https://dev.azure.com/****/ project=***
            
az pipelines variable-group variable update --id 365 --name release.version --value **-Release-1.2.0
```

I've tried a few differnt flavours, either running in powershell or adding the PAT token manually or not at all and either get AzureCLI just hanging and not progressing the task. If I get an error message, this is what I get:

```
ERROR: TF400813: The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.
```

Any help would be amazing. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

> The user 'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.

The error shows that the user accessing the resources with anonymous access.

I hope you are logged in with **`az devops login`** only once when running the pipeline. If not avoid multiple logins.

```vhdl
echo $Pat_key| az devops login
```

#### Steps to fix the issue:

1. while running the pipeline you are getting the User is not authorized to access this resource error make sure it has a valid resource access. If the user has access to the resources, please make sure to clear the cache before running the script. (The organization is connected to AAD, and the user has part of the AAD)
2. Reset the **[PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=Windows#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access)** token resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well. Locally in powershell this was working fine, only through azure devops pipelines I got this error.

Locally it worked so definitely its not a PAT issue.

Later I figured out you dont even have to use azure devops login before running azure devops configure if you are using PAT as environment variable.

Here is an example

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: Test run
  condition: and(succeeded())
  env:
  AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT)

Create a variable group with the above name and set it as secret value.

Refer this for more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows